# A different "Unable to instantiate activity" Error

Tags: android, android-listview

When I run my program it crashes and my logcat says "Unable to instantiate activity".

Now I know you're thinking it says that I didn't write my activity in my manifest, but it's something different.

I really don't know how to explain it nor fix it so I'm just going to let you guys look at it and hope that you can tell me what is going on. Also let me know if you still want to see my manifest.

```
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.theproblemsolver/com.theproblemsolver.ListView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at com.theproblemsolver.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:46)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
08-05 22:53:33.356: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  ... 11 more
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText et;
    Button getanswer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        Button getanswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        getanswer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListView.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

ListViewActivity:

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionList;

    //JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromURI(URI);

    final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
    final String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";
    final String TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
    final String TAG_QUESTION = "Question";
    final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
    final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
    final String TAG_ANSWERS = "Answers";
    final String TAG_ANSWER = "Answer";
    final String TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT = "Content";

    JSONArray results;

    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final String searchTerm = et.getText().toString().trim();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.listview);
        //questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new LoadAllData().execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == 100) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    class LoadAllData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {

                String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
                String URL = "http://example.com/json";
                JSONObject jObj = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
                try {
                    results = jObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

                    for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                       JSONObject r = results.getJSONObject(i);

                       JSONObject Question = r.getJSONObject(TAG_QUESTION);
                       String Subject = Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
                       String NumAnswers = Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS);
                       String ChosenAnswers= Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                       String Content = Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

                       JSONObject Answers = Question.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS);
                       JSONObject Answer = Answers.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWER);
                       String Content1 = Answers.getString(TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT);

                       questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                       map.put(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
                       map.put(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS, NumAnswers);

                       questionList.add(map);
                    }



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return TAG_RESULTS ;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_URL) {

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                    R.layout.listview,
                    new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS }, new int[] {
                    R.id.Subject, R.id.NumAnswers });

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            android.widget.ListView lv = getListView();

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.theproblemsolver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">

     </uses-permission>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.theproblemsolver.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
             android:name="ListView"
             android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the / from the package name, Eclipse doesn't like that generally. And posting the Manifest would be helpful. Does the program run correctly without doing AsyncTasks? Un-Comment setContentView(...). That should be all the stuff to get a better idea of your problem. Also, use google as your main problem solver. There are a lot of already similar questions that have the same package name "com.theproblemsolver.listview", and also use similar methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here, in your ListView activity class (probably not a good idea to name it that way, will just create confusion with the Android ListView widget class):

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

There is no such View in the default layout that comes with ListActivity. Even if you supply a custom layout with such a View, findViewById() is going to fail before you have called setContentView().

Answer (score 0):

try to uncomment this line because Almost all activities interact with the user, so the Activity class takes care of creating a window for you in which you can place your UI with setContentView(View).so try below..

```
 setContentView(R.layout.listview);
```